# Taking mean of dummy in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

I am trying to find out the fraction of rows where two columns are not the same:

This code either gives one or zero (depending on how I define the dummy):

```
SELECT CAST(AVG(subq.ens) AS DECIMAL(10,7))
from (select INDDATO_DATO, INDTIDSPUNKT_DRGKONTAKT_DATO, LeveranceDato_DATO, 
    case 
    when INDDATO_DATO = INDTIDSPUNKT_DRGKONTAKT_DATO THEN 1
    else 0
    end as ens
    FROM [Patient_kval].[DRG2018].[V_DRG2018_DRGKONTAKTER]
    where LeveranceDato_DATO= '2019-03-27'
    ) subq
```

But I have solved the problem by counting two times and dividing, and the result is 35%. I.e. I have done this:

```
SELECT count(*)
FROM [Patient_kval].[DRG2018].[V_DRG2018_DRGKONTAKTER]
where LeveranceDato_DATO= '2019-03-27' and INDDATO_DATO = INDTIDSPUNKT_DRGKONTAKT_DATO; -- 1.954.352


SELECT count(*)
FROM [Patient_kval].[DRG2018].[V_DRG2018_DRGKONTAKTER]
where LeveranceDato_DATO= '2019-03-27';-- 5.441.763
```

But I would like to know what the problem with the first method.

Comment: So if you've solved the problem, what's the question?

Comment: @user1443098: It is my first subquery and I would like to know why it does not work.

Comment: But you said you solved the problem, @David. What what *doesn't* work, and **why**?

Comment: @Larnu: Why does the first method not work? Not all dummies are 1 or 0. So I should not get an average of either 0 or 1...

Comment: In the first example, you're taking the average of integers, not decimals.  You're casting your result *after* the average, by which point the damage has already been done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are taking an `avg` of integers and the result is casted to integer, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/avg-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017 . Use decimal constants instead.

```
SELECT CAST(AVG(subq.ens) AS DECIMAL(10,7))
from (select INDDATO_DATO, INDTIDSPUNKT_DRGKONTAKT_DATO, LeveranceDato_DATO, 
    case 
    when INDDATO_DATO = INDTIDSPUNKT_DRGKONTAKT_DATO THEN 1.0
    else 0.0
    end as ens
    FROM [Patient_kval].[DRG2018].[V_DRG2018_DRGKONTAKTER]
    where LeveranceDato_DATO= '2019-03-27'
    ) subq
```

Comment: Thanks it works! I did not need the `CAST` in the first select.